# Integration Tests on Geb / Spock + Selenium Grid do not run in parallel

Tags: selenium-grid, spock, geb, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have the following set-up: an integration tests project which has a suite of tests written in Groovy/Geb + Spock, which are running perfectly both using Selenium WebDriver and Selenium Grid (RemoteWebDriver).

The problem is that no matter how much I try to tweak the "system", I can't get the tests to run in parallel (i.e. although I have 3 slaves [nodes] registered to the hub, only one of the slaves actually receives the requests). I've enforced maxSession=1 to the Selenium nodes and tried different combinations of parallel=classes|methods, threadCount and fork settings in failsafe plugin configuration (pom.xml file).

I have the feeling that the problem lies somewhere between the maven configuration and selenium grid, probably in relation to Geb/Spock config.

Does any of you have any insight on this issue?

PS: someone suggested that running tests in parallel using Geb / Spock is not possible - because for some reason ?Geb? locks the JUnitRunner (not sure what this means).

Answer (score 2):

Add following configuration to your build.gradle file:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
        maxParallelForks = 3 // here three forks shall open in parallel
        forkEvery = 1
        include '**/*TestName*.class'   // name of your test class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are test frameworks, TestNG for example, that support parallel testing on the method level out of the box.
Spock, as an example to the contrary, does not support it.

But you do not have to have multithreading implemented by your test framework to make this work.
You can use your build tool to run test classes in parallel, both Maven and Gradle support this.

If you are using Maven, this documentation page and examples might help you:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html
Specifically have a look at "Forked Test Execution".

Answer (score 0):

You can run it for sure, The point is you have to put them (your tests) in threads. [Here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Concurrency+with+Groovy) is the link.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to do this, explicitly, in Geb? I've tried it and it didn't work. An generic example, like one that would gest a site like google.com would work. I just need to see the actual syntax of something that is an actual test that actually works.